# Using promise creates a slight delay in factory while acquiring jsonp

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

So I've been learning angularJS and now I managed to stumble on a frustrating "problem". Everything works in my code but the content has a slight delay. Delay is like 0.5 seconds after the page loads.

Code for factory:

```
app.factory('newsService',['$http', '$q', function($http, $q){
  var data = null;
  return {
      getNewsList: function() {
  var promise;
      promise = $http({
        method: 'JSONP',url: 'http://uptsearch.cloudapp.net/solr/rss/select?q=*%3A*',
        params:{'indent': true,
                'wt': 'json',
                'json.wrf': 'JSON_CALLBACK'}
        })
        .then(function(response){
          // cache the response
          data = response;
          return response;
    });

  return promise;
}
} ;
}]);
```

Code for my controllers

```
app.controller('detailedController', function($scope, $stateParams, newsService) {

    $scope.date = $stateParams.index;
    newsService.getNewsList().then(function(news){
    $scope.news = news;
    $scope.date2 = $scope.news.data.response.docs[$stateParams.index].date;
    $scope.title = $scope.news.data.response.docs[$stateParams.index].title;    
})  

});
```

I also want to say that im displaying content on a routed page. Maybe it's connected somehow? And what could cause this delay ?

BR's

Comment: You are making an external call to get some data so there will of course be a delay.  It is difficult to tell exactly what the issue is.

Comment: Completely agree w/ lucuma, this is an external call so no telling how long it will take, hence promises. That being said, you can use `resolve` when defining your routes in order to load the data prior to switching views. You can search for `resolve` here: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki

Comment: It seems like I have to improve my reading skills. Completely missed the resolve part of that page :/. Thanks. But didin't expect that delay anyways.